# Импортировать файл в таблицу с помощью SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, импорт

Есть файл вида:

```
наименование_1
наименование_2
наименование_3
наименование_4
...
```

Есть таблица с одним полем `NAME VARCHAR2`. Надо с помощью `sqlplus` этот файл загрузить в таблицу. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через [SQL*Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ).

Иначе через [External Tables](http://www.orafaq.com/node/848).

Answer (score 3):

Если файл с данными большой, то, как в уже ранее данном ответе, [*SQL*Loader*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-commands.html) или [*External Tables*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html).

А так обычно тем, что под руку попадётся. Например:

```
$ declare -x sqlplusflags="-l -s user/pass@oradb"
$ echo -e "item1\nitem2\nitem3" > items.dat
$ echo "create table items (item varchar2(64));" | sqlplus $sqlplusflags

  Table created.

$ < items.dat perl -lane 'print "insert into items values (\x27", $F[0], "\x27);";'| \
      sqlplus $sqlplusflags | sed '/^\s*$/d'
  1 row created.
  1 row created.
  1 row created.

$ echo -e "
    select item from items;
    drop table items;" | sqlplus $sqlplusflags

  ITEM
  ----------------------------------------------------------------
  item1
  item2
  item3

  Table dropped.
```